# Removing the first char of some words on a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following list.

```
filtered_sent = ['colombia', 'nnueva', 'revolución', 'nindustrial', 'npropuestas', 'foco', 'tecnologías', 'convergentes', 'ne', 'industrias', 'nvolumen', 'ncolombia', 'nartista', 'federico', 'uribe', 'npropuestas', 'foco', 'tecnologías', 'convergentes', 'ne', 'industrias', 'ntomo', 'ncolombia', 'nueva', 'nrevolución', 'nindustrial', 'vicepresidencia', 'república', 'colombia', 'ministerio', 'ciencia', 'tecnología', 'innovación', 'elías', 'niño', 'ruiz', 'jean', 'paul', 'allain', 'josé', 'alejandro', 'montoya', 'juan', 'luis']
```

I want to remove the first character of each word that starts with 'n'. (for example: 'nnueva', 'nartista', 'nindustrial', etc.)

I tried this but it is removing the first character of the word from ALL words of the list:

```
lista_A = [] 
for it in filtered_sent:
    for j in it:
        if j[0] == 'n':
            lista_A.append(it[1:])
```

Comment: The inner for loop is not needed here

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
filtered = [i[1:] if i[0] == 'n' else i for i in filtered_sent]
```

Comment: I'd add a check to make sure it's not an empty string:
`filtered = [i[1:] if (i and i[0] == 'n') else i for i in filtered_sent]`

Answer (score 1):

There is some logical issue with your code in if block.

It's better to compare both index and first char of the word.

This code works.

```
lista_A = [] 
for it in filtered_sent:
    for i,j in enumerate(it):
        if j == 'n' and i == 0:
            lista_A.append(it)
        
print(lista_A)
```

Comment: The inner loop is unecessary. Why would you iterate through each letter of the word, if you want to check just the first letter? Your proposed solution complexity is O(n²), while the problem can be solved in O(n). The solution can be linear instead of quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Using a built-in `str` function:

```
new_list = [word.removeprefix('n') for word in filtered_sent]
```

Comment: This will work only in Python 3.9+

Comment: I get the following error:                                                                                                                     
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-265-d005f0c46b02> in <module>
----> 1 new_list = [word.removeprefix('n') for word in filtered_sent]

<ipython-input-265-d005f0c46b02> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 new_list = [word.removeprefix('n') for word in filtered_sent]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removeprefix'

Comment: @MaríaPaula You are using an old Python version (before 3.9)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
list(map(lambda word: word[1:] ,filter(lambda x:(x[0]=="n"),filtered_sent)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question, the mistake is the second for loop ("for j in it:"). There's no need to iterate through each letter of each word. Instead of checking only if the first letter of each word is equal to 'n', your code is checking if any letter of the word is equal to 'n'. At each iteration of the inner for loop, both j and j[0] are a reference to the same specific letter.

You can add some print statements to your code to better understand what is happening.

```
lista_A = [] 
for it in filtered_sent:
    for j in it:
        print(f'it: {it}')
        print(f'j: {j}')
        print(f'j[0]: {j[0]}')
        if j[0] == 'n':
            lista_A.append(it[1:])
```

Try removing the second for loop, and change the if clause to check the first character of the word:

```
lista_A = [] 
for it in filtered_sent:
  if it[0] == 'n':
    lista_A.append(it[1:])
```

Comment: I already tried it but it doesn´t work :(

Comment: The code I suggested takes all the words starting with 'n', removes the first letter and add the resulting word to lista_A. Words not starting with 'n' won't be added to lista_A. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What result did you get? What do you expect lista_A to be?

Comment: you are rigth, thanks